# How to access props in other functions of imported modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let say i created a basic modules with simple functions like  `helper.js`

```
export function HelloChandu() { 
   //How to access navigator props from here.
}

export function HelloTester() {
  HelloChandu();
}
```

Then I imported this module in my component as `import * as Helper from './helper';`

In some element I then called `onpress={Helper.HelloTester.bind(this)}`  So by this now I can access this.props in `HelloTester` function but I can not access this.props in `HelloChandu` function.

**Question** : How can I access `this.props` from any function in my helper.js module ?  Like if there are 10-20 functions , and i don't have to pass as parameters around.

Thank You

Comment: Why not pass `this.props` as an argument to `HelloChandu` in your `HelloTester`?

Comment: because i think i will then have to pass it around to many functions and I don't like the idea of passing it around. I thought there could be easier way :S ( if there any )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that if you want to access this.props in one of your functions you will need to pass `this` explicitily or to bind all the functions to the current `this` before using them.

There are several ways to do so.

```js
function HelloChandu() { 
  alert(this.props);
}

function HelloTester() {  
  HelloChandu.apply(this);
  // HelloChandu.call(this);
  // HelloChandu.bind(this)();
  // this::HelloChandu(); // Experimental!
}

const obj = {
  props: 'my props'
}

HelloTester.bind(obj)()
```

An alternative way would be to wrap all the functions in another function.

```js
function helpers() { 
  const functions = {
    HelloChandu: () => {     
      alert(this.props);
    },

    HelloTester: () => {  
      functions.HelloChandu();    
    }
  };
  return functions;
}

const obj = {
  props: 'my props'
}

helpers.call(obj).HelloTester();
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can persist props to AsyncStorage, whenever you need, you can access this props.

2.Or if you are familiar with closure, you can do like this :

```
function Helper(ps) {

  function test() {
    console.log(ps.sex);
  }

  function test2() {
    console.log(ps.name);
  }

  return {
    test: test,
    test2: test2,
  }
}

var obj = Helper({name: 'abc', sex: 'male'});

obj.test(); 
obj.test2();
```

then you should export Helper, and `import Helper from 'Helper.js'`

Answer (score 0):

```
export function HelloChandu(_this) { 
   //How to access navigator props from here.
}

export function HelloTester(_this) {
  HelloChandu(_this);
}
```

Comment: Care for any explanation on the parts you added to the OP's code?